# How to justify a table on the right margin on a Tufte-book documentclass?

Tags: tables, margins, tufte

How can I justify a table on the right margin in a `tufte-book` documentclass as in the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\small Text &\includegraphics[width=0.66\linewidth,valign=c]{Figure.pdf}\\
\end{tabular}
\\
\caption{Text of caption.}%
\label{fig:Fig1}%
\forceversofloat% forces caption to be set to the left of the float
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's really unclear what you mean. Inside `figure*` the `\linewidth` (but it would be better to use `\textwidth` is set to the standard text width *plus* the margin size.

Comment: Also, figure* does not support [h], only [tp].